# Can I start the Windows Management Instrumentation service programatically?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, wmi

My application depends on [`WMI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) but some users have this turned off by default on their Windows. Is a good idea to start it programatically? if so, how do I do that? Any .NET/C/C++ are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa826517(v=vs.85).aspx), if the WMI service is not running it *"automatically starts when the first management application or script requests connection to a WMI namespace."*.

So you shouldn't need to start it manually. But if you would need to, the [ServiceController class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) would be one way:

```
using(ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("winmgmt"))
{
    sc.Start();
}
```

This requires you to reference and import the `System.ServiceProcess` namespace.

Comment: I guess it didn't work because the service wasn't only started, it was disable as well. I had to turn on it and start manually to it work

Comment: @Jack : You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24947650/3740093) on how to enable a service using the WinAPI.

Comment: This what I'm looking for, thanks! I'm unsure what name should I use as serviceName paramaeter? for example, I want to get user physical mac adress, I'm using this WQL query: `Select * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` the service name is `NetworkAdapterConfiguration`?

Comment: @Jack : I haven't examined his code thoroughly but I guess `serviceName` would be the same as I used, which is the system's identifier name: `winmgmt`.

Comment: @Jack : Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Note that if WMI is disabled, you shouldn't re-enable it without first asking for the user's permission.  It isn't your computer to reconfigure.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yep, I know that. I do ask use if he wants to turn on WMI. I just wanted to make the application be able to do it with a simple user's hit a button than he do it himself! To our end users it might be some work